# Reliably blocking email addresses

Tags: email

Part of my website allows users to recommend an item to a friend by sending them an email. In order to not cause any annoyance, I provide the receiver with an option to opt-out of receiving any further emails from us. As you'd probably predict, these email addresses then get stored on my blacklist.

However, I've run into an issue in the fact that many major email services provide more than one domain (e.g. gmail.com/googlemail.com). Is there any reliable way of blocking a user's email address and accounting for all these possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do certain things like looking up MX records for each address' domain, but this would be highly unreliable and lead to false positives. e.g.

```
example@gmail.com
example@googlemail.com
```

could be the same user with the same mailbox. But google also hosts many other corporate systems for email, and example@someotherhosteddomain.com will resolve to using Google's MX servers, but be a completely separate mailbox with a totally different user.

In the end, you'll just have to accept that in some cases, people may get the email again because they've been littering their account registrations with various "cloned" mailboxes of this type.